# jQuery to populate array-named form fields based on first entered text box value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with variable number of inputs as an array

```
<form>
<label for="same">all the same as first?</label>
<input type="text" id="foo[1]" name="foo[1]" value="" />
<input type="text" id="foo[2]" name="foo[2]" value="" />
<input type="text" id="foo[3]" name="foo[3]" value="" />
<input type="text" id="foo[4]" name="foo[4]" value="" />
<input type="text" id="foo[5]" name="foo[5]" value="" />
</form>
```

The idea is when i put some value in the first field (`foo[1]`) i need the jQuery or Javascript copy the value from `#foo[1]` into `#foo[2]`, `#foo[3]`, etc depending on the array.

Comment: What do you mean by _depending on the array_?

Comment: it means as per the db, the record loads. If there are two records in the db, it will be foo[1] and foo[2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need following behavior :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("input[id^=foo\\[]").prop("disabled",true); //disable all elements first
  $("input#foo\\[1\\]").prop("disabled",false); //then enable the first one 
  
  $("input#foo\\[1\\]").change(function(){
    var source = $(this);
    var currentVal = $(source).val();
    $("input[id^=foo\\[]").each(function(){
      if(!$(this).is(source))
        $(this).val(currentVal);
    });
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<label for="same">all the same as first?</label>
<input type="text" id="foo[1]" name="foo[1]" value="" />
<input type="text" id="foo[2]" name="foo[2]" value=""/>
<input type="text" id="foo[3]" name="foo[3]" value=""/>
<input type="text" id="foo[4]" name="foo[4]" value=""/>
<input type="text" id="foo[5]" name="foo[5]" value=""/>
</form>
```

Comment: Its working fine. Thank you so much. Is there a way if i enter the first field (foo[1]), rest of the fields (foo[2], foo[3] etc becomes readonly or disabled? or initially if its disabled also its fine.

Comment: Even if your foo[2], foo[3] etc are disabled(read only) at initially the above JS code will work. Please have a look at updated code snippet. I have made all input field disabled except first one where user will input the data.

Comment: disabled in html will not work for me since this page is generated by php and iam just calling a record like foo[$i] which is incremented in each loop. Is there a way to enable only foo[0] from script?

Comment: yes..thats absolutely possible. See the updated code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').on('input', function(){
    $(this).siblings().val($(this).val());
});
```

Couldn't tell if you just wanted the first or all.  If just the first, you can target with an id or jQuery.

```
$('input').eq(0).on('input', function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/5x8o1Lu7/5/)

HTML

```
<form>
    <label for="same">all the same as first?</label>
    <input type="text" id="foo[1]" name="foo[1]" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="foo[2]" name="foo[2]" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="foo[3]" name="foo[3]" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="foo[4]" name="foo[4]" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="foo[5]" name="foo[5]" value="" />
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
$("input[id=foo\\[1\\]").on("input", function (){
   $(this).siblings().val($(this).val());
});
```

And if you want the other to be readonly:

```
$("input[id^=foo\\[]:not([id=foo\\[1\\]])").attr("readonly", "readonly");
```

Comment: its fine but, the records are coming from the db. so how can i name the first record id to 'first'?

Comment: In that case, you can use like this.
`$(".copyTo:eq(0)").on("keyup", function(){
   $(".copyTo:gt(0)").val($(this).val()); 
});`

Comment: I updated my answer using your HTML, this is alot like @fauxserious answer.

Comment: Actually, @vijayP had a better selector, code updated again.